# Can I simply replace old rackmount motherboard with another motherboard?

Tags: rackmount, hardware, central-processing-unit

I have a 1U rackmount server lying around with an old Pentium 4 motherboard (Super Micro P8SCi). To upgrade this server (on a small budget), can I keep the case/chassis and simply replace the motherboard with a newer generation motherboard? If so, which class of motherboards must I look for?

Thanks in advance

P.S. - The motherboards I have in mind for this upgrade are either the Intel XEONs or Core i7's. And yes I'm aware I need new memory too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically it might be possible but is the chassis worth that much? Unless you can receive assurance that the new MB fits 100%, it may be too much grief. As noted you need new MB, RAM and CPU and possibly power supplies And keeping old power supplies would be asking for a failure.

Comment: +1 for old power supplies being a pain. People always overlook those.

Comment: Good point. The PSU issue did cross my mind but I ignored it. The thrill of turning nothing into something blinded me

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I wouldn't bother for a 1U box.  I've built a few rack-mount boxes over the years, but almost all 2U, simply because it's easier to fit things in and easier to buy stuff that will fit.

Comment: Like what things?

Comment: Fans, memory, daughter cards, hard drives, power and data cables, everything.  It's fun once or twice to fit all the pieces nicely in a 1U, but it's a lot faster with the extra space in a 2U.